# get MongoDb ObjectId in Django Serializer

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am creating a Django server using **django_rest_framework** and **mondogb(djongo)**. I want to use mongoDb generated ObjectId as primary key. How to get the mongoDb ObjectId from serializer class?

**This is my user model**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/profile_pics/', blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

**This is my user serializer**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 'name', 'description', 'profile_pic']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

**views.py**

```
class GetUserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        data = UserSerializer(User.objects.filter(id=request.id)).data
        return Response(data)
```

This returns a json object

```
{
    'id': '<id>' eg: 1 or 2 or 3 etc..
    'name': '<user-name>',
    'username': '<username>',
    'description': '<description>',
    'profile_pic': '<profile_pic>'
}
```

**But I want to get below mentioned id(mongoDb ObjectId)**

```
{
    'id': 621343a45048323e635c4ae6
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your user model needs to inherit from Djongo base model. But that way you loose a lot of functionalities that come with inheriting from the AbstractUser class.
My advise is to use a relational database for your user table then you can route other tables to use mongodb.

perhaps take a look at this:
[It explains how Django is better suited for relational databases.](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-can-i-login-users-while-using-djongo/3148)

Answer (score 0):

First we need to import this ObjectId

```
from bson import ObjectId
```

there is one get method mentioned below for getting the data based on objectID

```
employee = Employee.objects.get(_id= ObjectId(_id))
```